# Adsense page impressions is showing zero

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-adsense, advertising, impressions

I have created a new AdSense account for my blog and integrated ads with my blog, but I am getting zero page impressions. Google Analytics is showing 300 to 400 visitor per day.   AdSense, however, shows zero page impressions.

I have verified my pub-id. I don't know what the problem is. How do I contact the Google AdSense team about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It wouldn't surprise me if your site is in violation of Adsense policy, as it loads dozens of ads, including popups, and appears to just be an ad farm.

Comment: Uhh loading this page all the Ad's locked up my browser window. Maybe none of your 300-400 users are able to survive all the Ad's long enough to load your AdSense Ad's too? You could uhhhh try moving them higher to the page? Maybe reduce the content so there's less to load before the Ad attack starts?

Answer (score 3):

There could be several reasons for this:

1. Your visitors are using adblock software so the ads are never shown
2. Adsense can't find any ads that fit your site and is showing public service advertising
3. Your Adsense code is not being loaded either because it is incorrectly applied to your website or the page stops loading before it gets to that code
4. Users have JavaScript turned off

You can contact Google in their [Adsense support forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/). Maybe someone there can help you identify the problem.

Comment: Also that the site may be in violation of AdSense's policy (which it *still* is, six years later).

Answer (score 1):

My Ads Were Shown By Just Having Few Request Here are the following steps I made

1. Get More Requests You are saying that 400 imp but no ads just make another ad unit in same app it will start showing I also did this this method and ad started In my previous ad unit it have many request but no imp then i made another unit it started showing ads
2. Have patient in my account it take 4 days to show ads and my account was approved by google in 1 hr it take a lot of time to build inventory in the server so be patient you will have your ads
3. Complaint google at admob complaint they will check your app and chances of app is approved is 50-50%